# Using tr command in awk to replace forward slash with vertical bar

Tags: perl, awk, tr

I have a large file that contains some lines that look something like:

```
>m160505_c100980652550000001823221307061611/31156/269-572
```

I need to replace all the forward slashes with vertical bars. I think awk is a great way to do this- it is fast and is simple. However, I am not sure how to incorporate tr and | into the command. So far I have the following, but I need help to correct it.

```
awk '/^>/{tr{/}{|}; next}{print}' < Old.fasta > New.fasta
```

I am not opposed to writing a script for this, but I feel like awk might be faster way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: awk is not shell, it's a tool that shell calls to manipulate text, just like shell could call a C program. You should not expect to be able to call shell commands directly from awk just like you can't call them directly from a C program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` doesn't have a `tr` command/function, nor does it have an *easy* way to get the same effect. Since you tagged this "perl", I'm assuming you're also open to a perl oneliner:

```
perl -lpe '/^>/ and tr{/}{|}' < Old.fasta > New.fasta
```

does the same thing that the awk looks like it's trying to do; replace all `/` with `|` on lines beginning with `>`.

Comment: I know I said awk, but you are right. I am open to perl solutions, and happen to like this one the best out of the other, very good solutions posted. Thanks hobbs!

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is probably simplest here:

```
$ sed '/^>/ s/\//|/g' <<<'>m160505_c100980652550000001823221307061611/31156/269-572'
>m160505_c100980652550000001823221307061611|31156|269-572
```

- After matching `>` at the start of a line (`^`) - with the regex enclosed in (mandatory) delimiters `/.../`,
- `s/\//|/g` substitutes (`s`) a `|` for every (`g`) `/` (escaped as `\/`, because `/` is used as the regex delimiter).

Using alternate delimiter `@` for clarity: `sed s'/^>/ s@/@|@g'`.

---

A variant that works similarly to the separate `tr` utility, using `sed`'s `y` function:

```
sed '/^>/ y/\//|/' <<<'>m160505_c100980652550000001823221307061611/31156/269-572'
```

- Function `y` replaces any characters in the 1st argument *individually* with the *corresponding* character in the 2nd argument - note that this implies that that the 1st and 2nd argument *must* have the *same length*  (`tr` does not require this).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^>/{gsub("/","|")}1' file
>m160505_c100980652550000001823221307061611|31156|269-572
```

If you DID need a tr() function in awk you'd have to write it, e.g.:

```
$ cat tr.awk
function tr(oldStr,oldList,newList,     newStr,i,o2n,chr) {
    for (i=1; i<=length(oldList); i++) {
        o2n[substr(oldList,i,1)] = substr(newList,i,1)
    }
    for (i=1; i<=length(oldStr); i++) {
        chr = substr(oldStr,i,1)
        newStr = newStr (chr in o2n ? o2n[chr] : chr)
    }
    return newStr
}
{ print $0, "->", tr($0,"xyz","123") }

$ echo 'axbyczd' | awk -f tr.awk
axbyczd -> a1b2c3d
```